# export a survey in sharepoint 2007 to a different site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to export a survey to a different site collection in MOSS 2007.  I have tried to export the survey as a template and create the survey based on that template.  The catch is that I need to preserve the metadata about the survey.  (ie. who submitted each submission.).  When I use this method it appears as if I submitted each survey item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-time thing you can use Gary Lapointes stsadm extensions to import/export list: http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/

Exporting

> Here’s an example of how to export the
>   Documents list from the root site
>   collection:
>
> ```
>  stsadm –o gl-exportlist -url
> http://intranet/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
> -filename "c:\docs" -includeusersecurity -versions 4 -nofilecompression
> ```

Importing

> Here’s an example of how to import the
>   Documents list that we exported above
>   and re-target any links pointing to
>   the original documents so that they
>   now point to the new documents (note
>   that just like the built in import
>   operation if you specify
>   nofilecompression for the export you
>   must also specify it for the import):
>
> ```
>      stsadm –o gl-importlist -url "http://teamsites/" -filename
>  "c:\docs" -includeusersecurity
>  -updateversions 2 -nofilecompression -retargetlinks -sourceurl "http://intranet/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
> ```

Note: To use these commands You must [download](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/) and install them.